# Constexpr member function

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, c++20

Suppose I have a `struct` template `S` that is parametrized by an engine:

```
template<class Engine> struct S;
```

I have two engines: a "static" one with a `constexpr` member function `size()`, and a "dynamic" one with a non-`constexpr` member function `size()`:

```
struct Static_engine {
    static constexpr std::size_t size() {
        return 11;
    }
};

struct Dynamic_engine {
    std::size_t size() const {
        return size_;
    }
    std::size_t size_ = 22;
};
```

I want to define `size()` member function in `S` that can be used as a `constexpr` if the engine's `size()` is `constexpr`. I write:

```
template<class Engine>
struct S {
    constexpr std::size_t size() const {
        return engine_.size();
    }
    Engine engine_;
};
```

Then the following code compiles with GCC, Clang, MSVC and ICC:

```
S<Static_engine> sta;         // not constexpr
S<Dynamic_engine> dyn;

constexpr auto size_sta = sta.size();
const auto size_dyn = dyn.size();
```

Taking into account intricacies of `constexpr` and various "ill-formed, no diagnostic is required", I still have the question: is this code well-formed?

[Full code on Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/EF_uGE)

(I tagged this question with both [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) in case this code has different validity in these two standards.)

Comment: "*ill-formed, no diagnostic is required*" There's not a lot of that regarding `constexpr` functions. If you try to misuse their `constexpr` status, compilers are required to be noisy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is fine as written.

> **[dcl.constexpr]**
>
> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.constexpr#6) If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr
>   function template or member function of a class template would fail to
>   satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr
>   constructor, that specialization is still a constexpr function or
>   constexpr constructor, even though a call to such a function cannot
>   appear in a constant expression. If no specialization of the template
>   would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr
>   constructor when considered as a non-template function or constructor,
>   the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

The member may not appear in a constant expression for the specialization that uses `Dynamic_engine`, but as the paragraph above details, that does not make `S::size` ill-formed. We are also far from ill-formed NDR territory, since valid instantations *are* possible. `Static_engine` being a prime example.

The quote is from n4659, the last C++17 standard draft, and similar wording appears in the latest C++20 draft.

---

As for the evaluation of `sta.size()` as a constant expression, going over the list at [**[expr.const]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const) I cannot find anything that is disallowed in the evaluation itself. It is therefore a valid constant expression (because the list tells us what *isn't* valid). And in general for a `constexpr` function to be valid, there just needs to exist *some* set of arguments for which the evaluation produces a valid constant expression. As the following example form the standard illustrates:

```
constexpr int f(bool b)
  { return b ? throw 0 : 0; }           // OK
constexpr int f() { return f(true); }   // ill-formed, no diagnostic required

struct B {
  constexpr B(int x) : i(0) { }         // x is unused
  int i;
};

int global;

struct D : B {
  constexpr D() : B(global) { }         // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
                                        // lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on non-constant global
};
```

Comment: Would be helpful to include the example that this clause now has: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6

Comment: @Barry - I'm afraid I'm confused. This specific clause moved in numbering and is now p7. Is the example for the previous clause relevant here too? Genuine question.

Comment: They're pretty related. One's just for regular functions and one's for templates. Just generally, it's only ill-formed ndr if there does not exist a single formulation that is a constant expression. Otherwise, it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Functions may be marked as `constexpr` without being forced to be evaluated at compile-time. So long as you satisfy the other requirements for marking a function as `constexpr`, things are okay (returns a literal type, parameters are literals, no inline asm, etc.). The only time you may run into issues is if it's not actually possible to create arguments that satisfy the function being called as a *core constant expression*. (e.g., if your function had undefined behavior for all values, then your function would be ill-formed NDR)

In C++20, we received the [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) specifier that forces all calls to the function to be able to produce a compile-time constant (`constexpr`).

Comment: `consteval` is rather stronger than that—it says that every *call* must produce a constant expression (perhaps indirectly).

Comment: @DavisHerring: Well said. Updated for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but an alternative way:

```
struct Dynamic_Engine
{
  using size_type = size_t;

  size_type size() const
  {
    return _size;
  }

  size_type _size = 22;
};
struct Static_Engine
{
  using size_type = std::integral_constant<size_t, 11>;

  size_type size() const
  {
    return size_type();
  }
};

template <typename ENGINE>
struct S
{
  auto size() const
  {
    return _engine.size();
  }

  ENGINE _engine;
};

int main()
{
  S<Static_Engine>  sta;
  S<Dynamic_Engine> dyn;

  const auto size_sta = sta.size();
  const auto size_dyn = dyn.size();

  static_assert(size_sta == 11);
}
```

I had the same kind of problems and IMHO the easiest and more versatile solution is to use `std::integral_constant`. Not more needs to juggle with `constexpr` as the size information is directly encoded into the type

If you still really want to use `constexpr` (with its extra complications) you can do:

```
struct Dynamic_Engine
{
  size_t size() const
  {
    return _size;
  }

  size_t _size = 22;
};
struct Static_Engine
{
  static constexpr size_t size() // note: static 
  {
    return 11;
  }
};

template <typename ENGINE>
struct S
{
  constexpr size_t size() const
  {
    return _engine.size();
  }

  ENGINE _engine;
};

int main()
{
  S<Static_Engine>  sta;
  S<Dynamic_Engine> dyn;

  constexpr size_t size_sta = sta.size();
  const size_t size_dyn = dyn.size();

  static_assert(size_sta == 11);
}
```

Comment: The “static” choice need not in practice actually produce a single constant, so long as the object is usable in constant expressions its `size()` can be.

Comment: @DavisHerring thanks for the comment. Actually in my code I really use the `std::integral_constant` approach. For the `static` approach I have added `inline` that must fix that.

Comment: @DavisHerring, you are right plus I have misread your initial comment. I have removed all this. Sorry for the noise.