# constexpr-ness of std::initializer_list::size() vs std::array::size()

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, initializer-list

The `size()` member functions of `std::initializer_list` and `std::array` have identical signatures:

```
constexpr size_type size() const noexcept;
```

Both are `constexpr`. However, `std::array::size()` can be used in `constexpr` context, but `std::initializer_list::size()` can't:

```
std::initializer_list<int> il{1, 2, 3, 4};
constexpr std::size_t il_size = il.size();       // (1) - fails with GCC and Clang (*)

std::array<int, 4> arr{1, 2, 3, 4};
constexpr std::size_t arr_size = arr.size();     // (2) - OK
```

(*) The error is:

> ```
> in 'constexpr' expansion of 'il.std::initializer_list<int>::size()'
> error: the value of 'il' is not usable in a constant expression
> ```

[As far as I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866631/constexpr-member-function), the fact that (1) fails and (2) succeeds is perfectly reasonable because `constexpr` member function of a class template may fail to satisfy `constexpr` requirements.

I have two related questions:

1. Why isn't `std::initializer_list` implemented in a way such that `(1)` compiles? Is there something in the standard that prevents such an implementation?
2. Given that `(1)` fails, what is the purpose of marking `std::initializer_list::size()` as `constexpr`? The only use case seems to be this one:

   ```
   constexpr std::initializer_list<int> il{1, 2, 3, 4};   // note constexpr
   constexpr std::size_t il_size = il.size();
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why isn't `std::initializer_list` implemented in a way such that (1) compiles? Is there something in the standard that prevents such an implementation?

Yes, it's impossible. An `initializer_list` can have any size, you cannot during constant evaluation time get the size of an arbitrary runtime `initializer_list`. This is quite different from `std::array`, where a given `std::array<T, N>` has size `N`. One's size is variable, the other's is fixed.

This isn't really different from any other variable:

```
struct X { int i; };

X x{42};
constexpr X cx{17};

constexpr int i = x.i;   // error
constexpr int ci = cx.i; // ok
```

> Given that (1) fails, what is the purpose of marking `std::initializer_list::size()` as `constexpr`? The only use case seems to be this one

This is not the only use case, far from. `constexpr` member functions do not just permit you to invoke them on `constexpr` objects. They more generally permit you to invoke them *anywhere* during constant evaluation time.

That is, during any kind of constant evaluation, if you create an `initializer_list`, you can then use its size. A silly minimal example might be:

```
constexpr size_t four() {
    std::initializer_list<int> lst = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    return lst.size();
}

static_assert(four() == 4);
```

Note that `lst` itself is not a `constexpr` object, it's just some ephemeral thing that got created during the course of evaluating the call to `four()` during constant evaluation. But we still need that `size()` to be `constexpr` - invoking any non-`constexpr` function is a no-no.

From here you can extend it outwards to any arbitrary code you might want to run that at some point, during constant evaluation, wants to determine the size of an `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not that `std::initializer_list::size` cannot be used in a constant expression. For example, the following *probably* (see footnote) [should compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b61413c89e7d8d1a):

```
#include <initializer_list>
int main() {
    constexpr int x = (std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4}).size();
    static_assert(x == 4);
}
```

However, the way you have called it, what presumably happens is that the `size` method has to perform an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on a member of the `std::initializer_list` object and that violates the constraints on constant expressions (C++17 [expr.const]/(2.7)).

In my example, the corresponding lvalue-to-rvalue conversion occurs on "a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within
the evaluation of `e`;", which makes it allowed (C++17 [expr.const]/(2.7.4)).

In the `std::array` example, there is probably no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, since the template parameter is returned.

Footnote: See [LWG 2833](http://wg21.link/lwg2833).