# Why is std::array<T,N>::begin() a constexpr since C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, compile-time

As of C++17, [`std::array<T,N>::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/begin) is constexpr:

```
constexpr iterator begin() noexcept;
```

But how can the return of `begin` be known at compile time? For instance:

```
int main() {
  auto p = std::make_unique<std::array<int,2>>();
  auto it = p->begin();
}
```

Is perfectly legal code (although maybe a bit useless). The start of the underlying array and thus the iterator depend on the malloc'd address.

I have the sense that I am under a misapprehension of what [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) does as I don't see how **any** non-static member function could possibly be `constexpr`, especially if it (transitively) accesses data members.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058271/constexpr-ness-of-stdinitializer-listsize-vs-stdarraysize

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`constexpr` functions can be called in non-compiletime-constant expressions. Such calls are evaluated at runtime. Only when `constexpr` function is called in a compiletime-constant expression, is the function evaluated at compile time.

> But how can the return of begin be known at compile time?

It can be known at compile time when the array itself is a compile time constant.

The fact that it cannot be known at compile time when the array is not a compile time constant is not a problem because the function is executed at runtime in that case.

Comment: So constexpr functions have a constexpr return value if all their arguments (including `this`) are constexpr? Is that fair to say?

Comment: @bitmask If they are called from a compile time constant expression. This implies that all arguments are also constant expressions because an expression cannot be constant if it has non-constant sub-expressions.

Comment: @bitmask You can only really say "the output of a `constexpr` function is constant only if its inputs are". If the inputs are constant expressions, then it depends on what the function is doing. E.g. for `constexpr int func(int x) { return 17 / x; }`, in `int x; std::cin >> x; func(x);`, `func(x)` is not a constant expression because `x` is not a constant expression. `func(17)` is a constant expression. *But*, `func(0)` is not a constant expression, because of undefined behavior. Constant expressions [are defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5) by what they aren't, not by what they are.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the unique pointer to see the effect of compile time vs runtime evaluation. This does compile:

```
#include <array>

int main() {
  static constexpr std::array<int,2> p{1,2};
  constexpr auto it = p.begin();
}
```

But this does not:

```
#include <array>

int main() {
  std::array<int,2> p{1,2};
  constexpr auto it = p.begin();
}
```

Error:

```
<source>:5:18: error: constexpr variable 'it' must be initialized by a constant expression

  constexpr auto it = p.begin();    
                 ^    ~~~~~~~~~    
<source>:5:18: note: pointer to subobject of 'p' is not a constant expression    
<source>:4:21: note: declared here    
  std::array<int,2> p{1,2};
```

Sloppy speaking, the `constexpr` of `begin()` means that it is possible to evaluate the method at compile time on a `constexpr` object. For the non-`constexpr` array, the method is evaluated at runtime. Hence `p.begin()` cannot be used to initialize the `constexpr it`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem this change solves is the ability to use a **non**`-const` `std::array` within a `constexpr` function to compute some result.  Recall that `constexpr` functions can't call non-`constexpr` functions when being evaluated at compile-time.

As an example consider a function that computes the sum of i = 1 to N.  And for argument's sake consider a really stupid way of doing it (non-stupid examples exist in the real world, but are more complicated than this):  Create an array initialized with `{1, 2, 3, ...}` and then returning the sum of the elements of the `array`.

```
// Compute sum from i = 1 to N
template <unsigned N>
unsigned
sum() noexcept
{
    std::array<unsigned, N> a{};
    unsigned u = 1;
    for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i, ++u)
        *i = u;
    u = 0;
    for (auto const x : a)
        u += x;
    return u;
}
```

This works fine and can be called like this:

```
auto x = sum<5>();  // x == 15
```

Now somebody says:  Hey, let's compute this at compile time!

In C++17 this is as simple as slapping `constexpr` onto `sum` and `x`:

```
// Compute sum from i = 1 to N
template <unsigned N>
constexpr
unsigned
sum() noexcept
...

constexpr auto x = sum<5>();  // x == 15
```

But in C++14 this doesn't compile:

```
test.cpp:24:20: error: constexpr variable 'x' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr auto x = sum<5>();
                   ^   ~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:11:21: note: non-constexpr function 'begin' cannot be used in a constant expression
    for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i, ++u)
                    ^
```

And the reason it doesn't compile is because `array<T, N>::begin()` is not a `constexpr` function.