# static_assert within templated class constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, initializer-list

I am trying to create a sample array class which is initialiszed by a std::initializer_list. I would like to check if the size of the initializer list is not more than the size of the array during compile time. Since static assert can only evaluate constexpr, this code is not getting compiled.

```
#include<initializer_list>
#include<cstddef>

template <typename T , size_t _size>
class array
{

    private:
    T arr[_size];

    public:
    array()
    {
    }

    array(std::initializer_list<T> arrList)
    {
        static_assert(_size>arrList.size(),"too many initializers"); // error: non-constant condition for static assertion

    }

    ~array()
    {
    }

};

int main()
{
    array<int,4> arr = {1,2,3,4,5}; 


    return 0;
}
```

std::array already has this functionality, but i couldnt find its implementation in header file.

```
#include<array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int,5> arr= {1,2,3,4,5,6}; // error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<int, 5>’
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: For `array` it is not explicitly implemented. `array` uses aggregate initialization and there the compiler takes care, not the STL.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with `std::initializer_list`, `arrList.size()` cannot be used in a constant expression, although its `size()` member function is declared as `constexpr`. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058271/constexpr-ness-of-stdinitializer-listsize-vs-stdarraysize).

`std::array` uses [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), it doesn't have a constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list`. This is how `std::array` is typically [implemented](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/array):

```
template<typename T, std::size_t size>
struct array {
    T arr[size];
    /* member functions */
};
```

Alternatively (with slightly different syntax for calling a constructor), you can make a constructor that takes an array by reference:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t size>
class array {
public:
    template<std::size_t s>
    array(const T(& a)[s]) {
        static_assert(s <= size, "too many initializers");
    }
private:
    T arr[size];
};
```

Then

```
array<int, 4> arr({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}); // error: static_assert failed due to requirement
                                    // '5UL <= 4UL' "too many initializers"
```

will fail to compile thanks to `static_assert`. However, you'll need some tricks inside the `array` constructor to perform the actual initialization of `arr` data member (you can't do `arr(a)`).